# Basic and OAuth Authentication headers at the same time

Tags: objective-c, oauth-2.0, afnetworking

Is it possible to use Basic and OAuth authorization headers in the same request with AFNetworking (avoiding the overwriting) ?

I have this code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.infojobs.net/"];
AFOAuth2Client *OAuthClient = [[AFOAuth2Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:url clientID:kClientID secret:kClientSecret];

[OAuthClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];

[OAuthClient authenticateUsingOAuthWithPath:@"oauth/authorize" code:self.authorizationCode redirectURI:kInfoJobsRedirectURLString success:^(AFOAuthCredential *credential) {
    NSLog(@"Credentials: %@", credential.accessToken);
    if (![credential.accessToken isEqualToString:@""]) {
        self.isAuthenticated = YES;

        [AFOAuthCredential storeCredential:credential withIdentifier:@"kInfoJobsAccessToken"];


        [[InfoJobsAPI sharedClient] setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:credential.accessToken];

        // (!) This overwrites the Authorization header set with the accessToken
        [[InfoJobsAPI sharedClient] setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:kClientID password:kClientSecret];   

        success(credential);

    }
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);

}];
```

And I need a request like this:

```
GET /api/1/application HTTP/1.1
Host: api.infojobs.net
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
Authorization: OAuth 07d18fac-77ea-461f-9bfe-a5e9d98deb3d
....
```

But I can't set the "Basic" and "OAuth" Authorization headers in the same request because AFNetworking seems to overwrite this header as seen in [documentation](http://afnetworking.github.com/AFNetworking/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken%3a)

It's possible to use "Basic" and "OAuth" in a same Authorization header, maybe splitting both with a "\n" ?

Thanks, and sorry for my poor english

---

**Edit**

Finally, I can use the "Basic" and "Oauth" authentications in the same header, this is the code:

```
[[InfoJobsAPI sharedClient] setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:kClientID password:kClientSecret];

AFOAuthCredential *credential = [AFOAuthCredential retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:@"kInfoJobsAccessToken"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"/api/2/candidate" parameters:nil];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"OAuth %@", credential.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    DLog(@"Response : %@",JSON);
}failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    DLog(@"Error : %@",error);
}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: I'm curious how your solution there works.  By putting "OAuth xxx(token)xxx" as an added value to your Authorization header, whatever server you're communicating with knows to check that portion of the Auth header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the HTTP specification there can be only one `Authorization` header in a request. So the behavior the library is showing is correct according to that specification: the second call to `setAuthorizationHeader...` overwrites the previous one.

What you'll typically see in HTTP is that there is a handshaking phase, where the server tells the client what authorization protocols it can accept. The client can then choose from those protocols, which one it wants to use.